# How can I create files and zip them without writing the files to disc?

Tags: php, zip, createfile

I want to create 5 different files that store data from my database. I want to zip up the 5 files and have this function return the zip.

Can I create the 5 files without actually writing them to disk? The data I get from the db are only strings, so each file will be a long string.

I simply want to do this:

```
function getZippedFiles()
 // Create 1..5 files
 // Zip them up
 // Return zip
end

main()
// $zip_file = getZippedFiles();
end
```

Any information on how to do this is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, it's pretty simple with **[ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)**

```
// What the array structure should look like [filename => file contents].
$files = array('one.txt' => 'contents of one.txt', ...);

// Instantiate a new zip archive.
$zip_file = new ZipArchive;

// Create a new zip. This method returns false if the creation fails.
if(!$zip_file->open('directory/to/save.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
    die('Error creating zip!');
}

// Iterate through all of our files and add them to our zip stream.
foreach($files as $file => $contents) {
    $zip_file->addFromString($file, $contents);
}

// Close our stream.
$zip_file->close();
```

Comment: is it possible to just return $zip_file instead of saving it to disc?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: I will be passing down the zip to another script, which will then unzip and write it to disc. The script that creates the zip lives on a different server, that's why I want to pass it down as a zip to make it faster.

Comment: I don't think that's the best way of approaching what you are trying to do. Why not post the database data to the script? Better yet, if you can, combine the scripts?

Comment: I'm requesting the zip file via http, so combining the script is impossible. Hmmm